# Maior item de uma lista de compras

Tags: python

Preciso encontrar o item mais caro dentro de uma lista.

A entrada deve conter o código do produto, a quantidade e o preço inseridos pelo usuário na mesma linha nessa ordem e cada linha é um produto. Aí o código precisa calcular a quantidade * o valor de todos os produtos que o usuário inserir e verificar qual é o item mais caro dentro dos itens inseridos.

A saída deve ser o código do produto, a quantidade e o valor somente do item mais caro entre todos os itens inseridos.

Tentei de absolutamente tudo o que conheço e não consigo resolver porque não consigo fazer o break do loop infinito.

Código

```
temp = []

listacustos = []

maior = 0

while True:

    item = input().split()
    temp.append(item)
    if len(temp) == 0:
        print ("nao tem compras")
    else:
        qtd = int(item[1])
        valor = float(item[2])
        custo = valor * qtd
        item.append(custo)
        listacustos.append(custo)
    for c in range(len(listacustos)):
        if listacustos[c] > maior:
            maior = listacustos[c]
    for p in temp:
        if p[2] == maior:
            print("Quantidade: {}".format(p[0]))
            print("Codigo: {}".format(p[1]))
            print("Custo: {}".format(p[3]))
```

Comment: Se quer saber como abandonar um loop, troque o título por algo mais descritivo. Ex: *"Como abandonar o loop while true: ?"* e comece a pergunta por, *"Fiz um programa que calcula o maior valor de uma lista de compras, o código está envolvido num laço `while true:` gostaria de saber como encerar esse laço depois que o usuário digitasse `0 0 0`?"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, apesar da minha solução estar diferente da sua, dê uma analisada no código e veja se ajuda.

```
# Lista de produtos
produtos = []

while True:
    # Entrada
    if input('Adicionar novo produto? s/n: ') != 's':
        # Obtém o maior 
        maior_valor = [0,0,0]
        for produto in produtos:
            if produto[2] > maior_valor[2]:
                maior_valor = produto
        
        # Saída
        print(f'Código: {maior_valor[0]}')
        print(f'Qtde: {maior_valor[1]} un.')
        print(f'Valor: R$ {maior_valor[2]:.2f}')
        break
    
    # Entrada
    codigo, qtde, preco = [i for i in input().split()]
    
    # Adiciona produto na lista de produtos
    produtos.append([codigo, qtde, float(preco)*float(qtde)])
```

Comment: Ah sim. Fiz uma comparação aqui e esqueci de mencionar que o loop infinito termina quando o usuário digita '0 0 0'. Mas consegui corrigir algumas coisas. Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

linha 7

```
while True: # este laço não tem break
```

linha 9

```
item = input().split() # aqui não foi usado como lista, mas algumas linhas abaixo há item.append() o que gera erro
```

linha 11

```
if len(temp) == 0: # ficaria melhor assim: if not temp:
```

linha 17

```
item.append(custo) # a variável precisa está associada a uma lista para poder usar .append(custo), ESTA LINHA GERA ERRO
```

linha 20

```
if listacustos[c] > maior: # Erro: não foi criada uma variável nomeada maior, ESTA LINHA GERA ERRO
```